# Messed up hyperref with redefined align environment

Tags: macros, hyperref, align, environments

I created new align-environments that places a "I." (or "II.") in front of the number of the equation (for example, I want to use I.1, I.2, etc. in the first part of my document and II.1, II.2, etc. in the second). However, the hyperrefs don't work correctly. If I click on a reference to II.2, for example, I end up at I.1.

In a simplified example, it works:

```
    \documentclass[
12pt,
a4paper,
titlepage]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%*********************************************************
%****Define new align-environments
%*********************************************************
% I.
\newcommand{\thealignedIal}{I.\arabic{equation}}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{romanalignI}{%
    \let\theequation\thealignedIal
    }{}
\makeatother

%% II.
\newcommand{\thealignedIIal}{II.\arabic{equation}}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{romanalignII}{%
    \let\theequation\thealignedIIal
    }{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This is part I of my document, so I would like to use \textit{romanalignI}: 
\begin{romanalignI}
\begin{align}
1+1 = 2 \label{eq1}
\end{align}
\end{romanalignI}

Now a second equation: 
\begin{romanalignI}
\begin{align}
2+2 = 4 \label{eq2}
\end{align}
\end{romanalignI}

It works fine when referencing them: \eqref{eq1} and \eqref{eq2}. \\

\newpage

Now, let's move on to part II and use \textit{romanalignI}: 
\begin{romanalignII}
\begin{align}
1+1 = 2 \label{eq3}
\end{align}
\end{romanalignII}

Now a second equation: 
\begin{romanalignII}
\begin{align}
2+2 = 4 \label{eq4}
\end{align}
\end{romanalignII}

Again, the referencing works fine: \eqref{eq3} and \eqref{eq4}.
\end{document}
```

But in the "real" document it stopps working properly:

**Master Document**

```
\documentclass[
12pt,
titlepage]{article}

% Space before/after align
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} % strike through text
\usepackage{scrextend}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\definecolor{primary}{HTML}{08457E}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath, bm}
\usepackage{physics} % for partial derivatives with \pdv
\usepackage{microtype} % für die Mikrotypografie (besseres Schriftbild)
\usepackage{lscape} %singles pages as landscape
\usepackage{rotating} % for 'sidewaystable' environment
\usepackage{tikz} %econ drawing
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{subfig} %tables next to each other

% allow for different spacing options 
\usepackage{setspace} 
\doublespacing

% allow for different spacing options in enumerate/itemize
\usepackage{enumitem}

%Formatierung Bilder
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{just_a_colon}{: }
\captionsetup[figure]{
    position=below,
    labelsep=just_a_colon
}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{1em}}
\makeatother

%Hyperlinks 
\usepackage{hyperref}
% colored links
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,%set true if you want colored links
    linktoc=all,
    %set to all if you want both sections and subsections        linked
    filecolor=black,
    citecolor={blue!40!black},
    linkcolor={blue!40!black},
    urlcolor=black,
    %linktocpage, 
    %only link the page numbers and not the entire table    of contents
}

% For Tables
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=space, 
         justification=raggedright, singlelinecheck=off}
\usepackage{caption,threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array} %center with m{} 
%-> ">{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.3\linewidth} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.3\linewidth}"
\usepackage{tablefootnote}

% Appendix
\usepackage[title]{appendix}

%Gliederungsebenen
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}


\usepackage[bottom, hang, flushmargin]{footmisc} % put footnote as much to the bottom as possible AND no indent

% no indentation of new lines
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

% set font to Times New Roman
\usepackage{times}

% add table of figures/tables to table of contents
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} 

% widow / orphan control
\usepackage[all]{nowidow}


\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  left=20mm,
  right=20mm,
  top=10mm,
  bottom=30mm,
  scale=1 %,
  %showframe
  ]{geometry}       % Seitenränder und Bindungskorrektur einstellen
  
\setlength{\headsep}{0.3in} % add space between header and text

%*********************************************************
%****CUSTOM COMMANDS
%*********************************************************
\newcommand{\submissiondate}{INSERT SUBMISSION DATE}
% Define checkmark
\usepackage{pifont}
\newcommand{\checkmark}{\ding{51}}
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}

\usepackage{accents}
\newcommand{\ubar}[1]{\underaccent{\bar}{#1}}


%*********************************************************
%****Define new align-environments
%*********************************************************
% Römisch Erstens
\newcommand{\thealignedIal}{I.\arabic{equation}}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{romanalignI}{%
    \let\theequation\thealignedIal
    }{}
\makeatother

%% Römisch Zweitens
\newcommand{\thealignedIIal}{II.\arabic{equation}}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{romanalignII}{%
    \let\theequation\thealignedIIal
    }{}
\makeatother
%*********************************************************
%****Formatierung des Titelblatts
%*********************************************************
\title{%
  This is the title}
\newcommand*\mytitle{}
\makeatletter
\let\mytitle\@title
\makeatother

%\linespread{1.5}
\pagestyle{myheadings}

\setlength{\headheight}{1.8\baselineskip}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot

% Colorboxes
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[3][]
{
  colframe = #2!25,
  colback  = #2!10,
  coltitle = #2!20!black,  
  title    = {#3},
  #1,
}

%*********************************************************
%****BEGIN DOCUMENT
%*********************************************************
\begin{document}

%*********************************************************
%****GENERATE TITLEPAGE
%*********************************************************
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}

\vspace*{0.5cm}

{\bfseries\Large\textsc{\mytitle}}\\

\vspace*{2.5cm}


{more text}\\

\vspace{1cm}

Name of Institution  \\

\vspace{2cm}

City, \submissiondate
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\newgeometry{
  left=33mm,
  right=23mm,
  top=23mm,
  bottom=23mm,
  scale=1}  

%*********************************************************
%****ABSTRACT
%*********************************************************
\vspace*{2cm}
\section*{\centering{Abstract}} \label{Abstract}
%\begin{center}
\begin{addmargin}[10pt]{10pt}
\input{./Kapitel/Abstract}
\end{addmargin}
%\end{center}
\newpage
%*********************************************************
%****GENERATE TABLE OF CONTENTS
%*********************************************************
\thispagestyle{empty} %no header/footer
{
\onehalfspacing
  \hypersetup{linkcolor=black}
  \tableofcontents
  \makeatletter
  \renewcommand*{\ext@figure}{lot}
  \let\c@figure\c@table
  \let\ftype@figure\ftype@table
  \let\listoftableandfigures\listoftables
  \renewcommand*\listtablename{List of Tables and figures}
  \makeatother
}

%*********************************************************
%****List of Figures / Tables
%*********************************************************
{
  \hypersetup{linkcolor=black}
  \listoffigures
  %\listoftables
}

%*********************************************************
%**** Manual Glossary
%*********************************************************
\newpage
\section*{Glossary}
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{tabular}{ll}     
c.p.       & ceteris paribus
\\ ~ \\               
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

%*********************************************************
%****BEGINN MAIN SECTION
%*********************************************************
%*********************************************************
%****PAGE NUMBERING
%*********************************************************
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}

%*********************************************************e
%****SET HEADER/FOOTER
%*********************************************************
\chead{\normalfont Title} %{Kopfzeile Mitte}
\ihead{{\normalfont Name}}%{Kopfzeile innen} %not italic
\ohead{\pagemark}%{Kopfzeile außen}
\ifoot%{Fußzeile innen}
\cfoot%{Fußzeile Mitte}
\ofoot%{Fußzeile außen}


\section{Introduction} \label{Introduction}
    \input{./Kapitel/Introduction}

\newpage
\section{Models} \label{Main}
    \input{./Kapitel/Main}
    
\newpage
\section{Conclusion} \label{Conclusion}
    \input{./Kapitel/Conclusion}

\newpage
 

\end{document}
```

**Chapters Called**
I call chapter seperately. They lie in a folder called "Kapitel".

*Abstract.tex*

```
Abstract
```

*Conclusion.tex*

```
Conclusion
```

*Introduction.tex*

```
Introduction
```

*Main.tex*

```
\subsection{Model 1}


 \setcounter{equation}{0}
    \input{./Kapitel/Model1}
    
    \newpage
    blabla
    \newpage
    blabala
    \newpage
    
    \subsection{Model 2}
    \setcounter{equation}{0}
    \input{./Kapitel/Model2}
```

*Model1.tex*

```
\subsubsection{Equ1}
\begin{romanalignI}
\begin{align}
1+1 = 2 
\label{eq I.1}
\end{align}
\end{romanalignI}


\subsubsection{Eq 2}
\begin{romanalignI}
\begin{align}
1+1 = 2 
\label{eq I.2}
\end{align}
\end{romanalignI}

\subsubsection{Referencing both}
\eqref{eq I.1} and \eqref{eq I.2}.
```

*Model2.tex*

```
    \subsubsection{Equ1}
\begin{romanalignII}
\begin{align}
1+1 = 2 
\label{eq II.1}
\end{align}
\end{romanalignII}


\subsubsection{Eq 2}
\begin{romanalignII}
\begin{align}
1+1 = 2 
\label{eq II.2}
\end{align}
\end{romanalignII}

\subsubsection{Referencing both}
\eqref{eq II.1} and \eqref{eq II.2}.
```

I can't figure out what is causing the mess up and would be very, very thankful for any help!

Comment: try to minimize your failing example by removing one by one packages until you find the culprit.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. On fully updated MacTeX2022 distribution, I am unable to reproduce the issue you say you're getting. Please tell us which TeX distribution you employ and when you last updated it.

Comment: Aside: You should almost certainly delete the preamble instruction `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}`. You'd also be well advised to replace `\usepackage{times}` with `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I am working with MiKTeX 21.3, last updated in April 2021... So that might well be the problem! I will update it and see if the problem persists.

Comment: About your equation numbering system: Do you simply want equations numbers to be displayed in the style `\Roman{section}\arabic{equation}`? And, should equation numbers be reset automatically whenever a `\section` directive is encountered?

Comment: No, not exactly. My document is structured as follows: 1) Introduction 2) Model 1 3) Model 2 4) Conclusion and I would like the equations for model 1 to start with "I." and equations for model 2 to start with "II.". But the roman number does not correspond to the section number as model 1 is in section 2 etc.

Comment: @Mico regarding your other advice: Why would you not recommend using \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} and \usepackage{times}?

Comment: Update: Having updated MiKTeX 21.3, the example I presented above works for me, too. However, it still does not work in my "real" document, in which I am trying to use it. I am now even more confused than I was before because I was so far not able to produce an example in which the problem from my real document arises... Do you have any intution whatsoever why this might be happening? Or is there maybe another way / more elegant way to create such an equation numbering system? Thank you very much for all of your advice so far!!

Comment: Nowadays, `utf8` is the default input encoding used almost everywhere, unless you seriously go out of your way to impose a different input encoding scheme. About 3 or 4 years ago, the LaTeX kernel switched to using `utf8` as the default input encoding scheme.  The `latin1` and `latin9` input encoding are almost certainly not appropriate today. The `times` package loads a Times Roman text font, but does nothing for math fonts. Loading the `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` packages will assure that the fonts match and don't interfere with each other.

Comment: If the problem no longer surfaces in the test document but is still present in your real document, I suggest you edit your posting to show something closer to the real document.

Comment: I updated the example. I am sorry for its length, but in this way the problem arises and its structure is very similar to the structure of my document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the definitions into

```
% Römisch Erstens
\newcommand{\thealignedIal}{I.\arabic{equation}}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{romanalignI}{%
    \let\theequation\thealignedIal
    \renewcommand\theHequation{\thealignedIal\arabic{equation}}%
    }{}
\makeatother

%% Römisch Zweitens
\newcommand{\thealignedIIal}{II.\arabic{equation}}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{romanalignII}{%
    \let\theequation\thealignedIIal
    \renewcommand\theHequation{\thealignedIIal\arabic{equation}}%
    }{}
\makeatother
```

I also suggest to add `\pagenumbering{Alph}` before the `titlepage` and `\pagenumbering{alph}` after it, so you don't get duplicate anchors (the page numbering won't appear anyway). Never use `\pagenumbering{gobble}` when `hyperref` is involved.

Comment: Thanks a LOT, @egreg, this solution works flawlessly! 

Also thanks again to Mico for all of your helpful comments :)